# rtmpdump produce bigger output then rtmpsuck

Tags: video, rtmp

When using `rtmpsuck` the video has right size according to metadata  ~316MB:

```
INFO:   datasize              330537967.00
```

but when I use `rtmpdump` the output has 880MB at 35%

Only important exception is **Overall bit rate** reported by `mediainfo`:

```
$ diff rtmpsuck rtmpdump -y
File size                 : 316 MiB            | File size               : 803 MiB
Duration                  : 1h 37mn            | Duration                : 34mn 27s
Overall bit rate mode     : Variable             Overall bit rate mode   : Variable
Overall bit rate          : 454 Kbps           | Overall bit rate        : 3 259 Kbps

Video                                            Video
Duration                  : 1h 37mn            | Duration                : 34mn 27s
Bit rate                  : 293 Kbps             Bit rate                : 293 Kbps
Stream size               : 205 MiB (65%)      | Stream size             : 205 MiB (26%)

Audio                                            Audio
Duration                  : 1h 37mn            | Duration                : 34mn 27s
Bit rate mode             : Variable             Bit rate mode           : Variable
Bit rate                  : 154 Kbps             Bit rate                : 154 Kbps
Compression mode          : Lossy                Compression mode        : Lossy
Stream size               : 110 MiB (35%)      | Stream size             : 110 MiB (14%)
```

Any idea why `rtmpdump` is making bigger output file? And how to circumvent this?

```
$ rtmpdump --v
RTMPDump v2.4
```

tried Win version too: `RTMP Proxy Server 2.4 git-6230845 2011-9-25`